# How can i replace apt progress bar. I want to Put some special characters to make it look more like a progress bar

Tags: apt

i tried making 99progressbar in the directory /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/  and added this line of code

```
Dpkg::Progress-Fancy "::█";
```

at this point I'm just guessing lol

```
BEFORE
[######################] 
EFTER
[███████████████████████]
```

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using ubuntu

Comment: distro/version? don't add to the comment trail [edit] in to your question 

Comment: Add the information about your Ubuntu version [in your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1508452/edit).

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind using a third party client you can use nala because nala is  a commandline frontend for the APT package manager [image: sudo nala upgrade] using sudo nala upgrade we can see that it looks better then apt, you can also alias apt to nala so that you can still use apt in your commands

Comment: new problem my alias is not working for mapping nala to apt

Comment: @Vincent post your bash/zshrc please